# Measure how much activity is occurring within certain frequency values in Python

Tags: python, audio, frequency

I'm trying to find a way to obtain frequency values (in Hz) of an audio file, and measure how often these frequency values occur in proportion to the rest of the frequency values in that file.

For example, in an audio file, I'd like to see what proportion of the audio activity occurs within the 300 - 500 Hz range.

This would be simple if I could somehow get a list or an array filled with all frequency values of a given audio file, but I don't know how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is vague.  How do you define "how often these frequency values occur..."?  Is a 1 second burst of 300Hz considered a single occurrence?  What about a 1/2 second burst?  If both are counted equally then how do you use that to measure proportionality?  Does the amplitude of a frequency factor in? It also might be worth noting that all frequencies are essentially occurring at all times, just some more pronounced than others (e.g. noise floor).  What is your threshold for determining if a frequency is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) or [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).

From Wikipedia:

[image: Fourier Transform]

On the left would be your normal signal, and on the right is your frequency-domain signal. Of course, you can just cut out the 300-500 Hz range, take the integral over that area, then divide by the total area to get the proportion...

Not really my specialty, but consider a [scipy solution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html#scipy.fftpack.fft)?